# how to reset un-pushed commit without loosing local changes using git reset

Tags: git, github, pycharm, commit, reset

I want to push my files to a new repository that has yet no files(in GitHub).
I accidently committed un wanted files which are to big for GitHub so I can't push anything to the repository.
I  want to reset the commit before I try and push again.
I'm a bit confused on how to use correctly
git reset --soft/hard/mixed
when the final result I'm looking for is:
no change in my local repository, reset the files in the commit- so I can choose again which files to commit.

Comment: Short answer is `git reset HEAD^` but be sure to read a bit about the different modes [here](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Reset-Demystified).

Comment: i did : git reset HEAD~
than i got this : fatal: ambiguous argument 'HEAD~': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.

Comment: Initial commit I guess?

Comment: it is probably the initial commit, but thing is i have files there that arent supposed to be there,so how can i change initial commit?

Comment: Recreate the repo. No commits means no history so you just need contents in a folder to init. Local config and hooks are easy enough to transfer if needed.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this with git reset HEAD , this command will change your head commit

Comment: i did this, but than i got this: fatal: ambiguous argument 'HEAD~': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).